# Instant Run throw DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When **targetSdkVersion** is set below **21** in my project, gradle build works fine and project runs properly. Here is build.gradle file:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.air"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

But when **targetSdkVersion** is set **23** and instant run is enabled, it throws this exception:

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Why?

Instant Run is bit confusing to me. I am unclear how it works in Android Studio.

Comment: did you google it at all? `Instant Run: This feature is supposed to dramatically improve your workflow by letting you quickly see changes running on your device or emulator. It lets you see your changes running “in a near instant,” which means you can continuously code and run your app, hopefully accelerating your edit, build, run cycles. When you click on the Instant Run button, it will analyze the changes you have made and determine how it can deploy your new code in the fastest way. Instant Run works with any Android Device or emulator running API 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or higher.`

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

Comment: http://venturebeat.com/2016/04/07/google-launches-android-studio-2-0-with-instant-run-faster-android-emulator-and-cloud-test-lab/
As you can see, there are plenty of answers already out there. :)

Comment: This question is easily answerd by google https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is How to google what we need first!

Comment: All of you are right. Actually I should have asked the question more specifically. So I have edited the question according to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instant Run pushes updated code and resources to your connected device or emulator by performing a hot swap, warm swap, or cold swap. It automatically determines the type of swap to perform based on the type of change you made.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building a new APK, it pushes just those new changes and, in some cases, the app doesn't even need to restart but immediately shows the effect of those code changes.

Instant Run pushes updated code and resources to your connected device or emulator by performing a hot swap, warm swap, or cold swap.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It enables fast development by not requiring a full build and redeployment of the apk every time you make a change to your app's code. It pushes only the changes made and makes them available instantly.

There are three types of **swaps - HOT, WARM and COLD**. (In increasing order of time taken to reflect changes)

**HOT SWAPS** are triggered when

> Change implementation code of an existing instance method or static
>   method

**WARM SWAPS** are triggered when

> Change or remove an existing resource

**COLD SWAPS** are triggered when

> Structural code changes

To understand the exact behavior and different scenarios refer [the official documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)